# Find substring ignoring specified characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

Do any of you know of an easy/clean way to find a substring within a string while ignoring some specified characters to find it. I think an example would explain things better:

- **string:** "Hello, -this- is a string"
- **substring to find:** "Hello this"
- **chars to ignore:** "," and "-"
- **found the substring, result:** "Hello, -this"

Using Regex is not a requirement for me, but I added the tag because it feels related.

**Update:**

To make the requirement clearer: I need the resulting substring *with* the ignored chars, not just an indication that the given substring exists.

**Update 2:**
Some of you are reading too much into the example, sorry, i'll give another scenario that should work:

- **string:** "?A&3/3/C)412&"
- **substring to find:** "A41"
- **chars to ignore:** "&", "/", "3", "C", ")"
- **found the substring, result:** "A&3/3/C)41"

And as a bonus (not required per se), it will be great if it's also not safe to assume that the **substring to find** will not have the ignored chars on it, e.g.: given the last example we should be able to do:

- **substring to find:** "A3C412&"
- **chars to ignore:** "&", "/", "3", "C", ")"
- **found the substring, result:** "A&3/3/C)412&"

Sorry if I wasn't clear before, or still I'm not :).

**Update 3:**

Thanks to everyone who helped!, this is the implementation I'm working with for now:

- http://www.pastebin.com/pYHbb43Z

An here are some tests:

- http://www.pastebin.com/qh01GSx2

I'm using some custom extension methods I'm not including but I believe they should be self-explainatory (I will add them if you like)
I've taken a lot of your ideas for the implementation and the tests but I'm giving the answer to  @PierrOz because he was one of the firsts, and pointed me in the right direction.
Feel free to keep giving suggestions as alternative solutions or comments on the current state of the impl. if you like.

Comment: @Fredy take a look at my updated response which, if I understood correctly, should cover your updated scenarios.

Comment: @Fredy - is it safe to conclude that you expect both the input string and the search string to both be clean of the unwanted chars before searching?  If so, below I provided a solution using both RegEx and string searching.

Comment: @Ahmad - I like your update, I'm going to take some ideas from there, Thanks.

Comment: @Jamie You can assume the string to search for has no "ignored characters" on it, but it would be better if you allow this. In the case of the input string, it will definetly have "ignored chars" on it, that's de idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example you would do:

```
string input = "Hello, -this-, is a string";
string ignore = "[-,]*";
Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("H{0}e{0}l{0}l{0}o{0} {0}t{0}h{0}i{0}s{0}", ignore));
Match m = r.Match(input);
return m.Success ? m.Value : string.Empty;
```

Dynamically you would build the part [-, ] with  all the characters to ignore and you would insert this part between all the characters of your query.

Take care of '-' in the class []: put it at the beginning or at the end

So more generically, it would give something like:

```
public string Test(string query, string input, char[] ignorelist)
{
    string ignorePattern = "[";
    for (int i=0; i<ignoreList.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ignoreList[i] == '-')
        {
            ignorePattern.Insert(1, "-");
        }
        else
        {
            ignorePattern += ignoreList[i];
        }
    }

    ignorePattern += "]*";

    for (int i = 0; i < query.Length; i++)
    {
        pattern += query[0] + ignorepattern;
    }

    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
    Match m = r.Match(input);
    return m.IsSuccess ? m.Value : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hi!, I had already thought about this option and it definitely works for me.
I was looking for something cleaner that doesn't require me to build the regex dinamically. but you deserve the 'answered' if nothing like that appears. Regards.

Comment: yep I'm not sure we can avoid something like this. Besides, in the ignore list we would have to take care of such characters as "?" or "+" and all the ones used in the regex syntax. There's sill some work on the Test method :)

Comment: You are right, but it's ok if that's left as an exercise to me :). If I come to implement it this way I'll try to remember to update the question with the more generalized implementation or a link to it. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** here's an updated solution addressing the points in your recent update. The idea is the same except if you have one substring it will need to insert the ignore pattern between each character. If the substring contains spaces it will split on the spaces and insert the ignore pattern between those words. If you don't have a need for the latter functionality (which was more in line with your original question) then you can remove the `Split` and `if` checking that provides that pattern.

Note that this approach is not going to be the most efficient.

```
string input = @"foo ?A&3/3/C)412& bar A341C2";
string substring = "A41";
string[] ignoredChars = { "&", "/", "3", "C", ")" };

// builds up the ignored pattern and ensures a dash char is placed at the end to avoid unintended ranges
string ignoredPattern = String.Concat("[",
                            String.Join("", ignoredChars.Where(c => c != "-")
                                                        .Select(c => Regex.Escape(c)).ToArray()),
                            (ignoredChars.Contains("-") ? "-" : ""),
                            "]*?");

string[] substrings = substring.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string pattern = "";
if (substrings.Length > 1)
{
    pattern = String.Join(ignoredPattern, substrings);
}
else
{
    pattern = String.Join(ignoredPattern, substring.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray());
}

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0} -- Match: {1}", match.Index, match.Value);
}
```

---

Try this solution out:

```
string input = "Hello, -this- is a string";
string[] searchStrings = { "Hello", "this" };
string pattern = String.Join(@"\W+", searchStrings);

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

The `\W+` will match any non-alphanumeric character. If you feel like specifying them yourself, you can replace it with a character class of the characters to ignore, such as `[ ,.-]+` (always place the dash character at the start or end to avoid unintended range specifications). Also, if you need case to be ignored use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

If your substring is in the form of a complete string, such as "Hello this", you can easily get it into an array form for `searchString` in this way:

```
string[] searchString = substring.Split(new[] { ' ' },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex string extension option:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool SubstringSearch(this string s, string value, char[] ignoreChars, out string result)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("Search value cannot be null or empty.", "value");

        bool found = false;
        int matches = 0;
        int startIndex = -1;
        int length = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length && !found; i++)
        {
            if (startIndex == -1)
            {
                if (s[i] == value[0])
                {
                    startIndex = i;
                    ++matches;
                    ++length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (s[i] == value[matches])
                {
                    ++matches;
                    ++length;
                }
                else if (ignoreChars != null && ignoreChars.Contains(s[i]))
                {
                    ++length;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = -1;
                    matches = 0;
                    length = 0;
                }
            }

            found = (matches == value.Length);
        }

        if (found)
        {
            result = s.Substring(startIndex, length);
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want, although I suggest you modify it to fit your needs better:

```
string resultString = null;

try
{
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, "Hello[, -]*this", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more general, my example was just that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a single Regex but it would be quite tedious as after every character you would need to test for zero or more ignored characters. It is probably easier to strip all the ignored characters with `Regex.Replace(subject, "[-,]", "");` then test if the substring is there.

Or the single Regex way

```
Regex.IsMatch(subject, "H[-,]*e[-,]*l[-,]*l[-,]*o[-,]* [-,]*t[-,]*h[-,]*i[-,]*s[-,]*")
```

Comment: Hi, I think I can't strip the characters because I need the resulting substring with the chars. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-regex way to do it using string parsing.

```
    private string GetSubstring()

    {
        string searchString = "Hello, -this- is a string";
        string searchStringWithoutUnwantedChars = searchString.Replace(",", "").Replace("-", "");

        string desiredString = string.Empty;
        if(searchStringWithoutUnwantedChars.Contains("Hello this"))
            desiredString = searchString.Substring(searchString.IndexOf("Hello"), searchString.IndexOf("this") + 4);

        return desiredString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, since most all of these answer require rebuilding the string in some form.

string1 is your string you want to look through

```
//Create a List(Of string) that contains the ignored characters'
List<string> ignoredCharacters = new List<string>();

//Add all of the characters you wish to ignore in the method you choose

//Use a function here to get a return

public bool subStringExist(List<string> ignoredCharacters, string myString, string toMatch)
{
    //Copy Your string to a temp

    string tempString = myString;
    bool match = false;

    //Replace Everything that you don't want

    foreach (string item in ignoredCharacters)
    {
        tempString = tempString.Replace(item, "");
    }

    //Check if your substring exist
    if (tempString.Contains(toMatch))
    {
        match = true;
    }
    return match;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a combination of RegEx and string searching

```
public class RegExpression {

  public static void Example(string input, string ignore, string find)
  {
     string output = string.Format("Input: {1}{0}Ignore: {2}{0}Find: {3}{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine, input, ignore, find);
     if (SanitizeText(input, ignore).ToString().Contains(SanitizeText(find, ignore)))
        Console.WriteLine(output + "was matched");
     else
        Console.WriteLine(output + "was NOT matched");
     Console.WriteLine();
  }

  public static string SanitizeText(string input, string ignore)
  {
     Regex reg = new Regex("[^" + ignore + "]");
     StringBuilder newInput = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (Match m in reg.Matches(input))
     {
        newInput.Append(m.Value);
     }
     return newInput.ToString();
  }
```

}

Usage would be like

```
RegExpression.Example("Hello, -this- is a string", "-,", "Hello this");  //Should match
RegExpression.Example("Hello, -this- is a string", "-,", "Hello this2"); //Should not match
RegExpression.Example("?A&3/3/C)412&", "&/3C\\)", "A41"); // Should match
RegExpression.Example("?A&3/3/C) 412&", "&/3C\\)", "A41"); // Should not match
RegExpression.Example("?A&3/3/C)412&", "&/3C\\)", "A3C412&"); // Should match
```

Output

Input: Hello, -this- is a string
Ignore: -,
Find: Hello this

was matched

Input: Hello, -this- is a string
Ignore: -,
Find: Hello this2

was NOT matched

Input: ?A&3/3/C)412&
Ignore: &/3C)
Find: A41

was matched

Input: ?A&3/3/C) 412&
Ignore: &/3C)
Find: A41

was NOT matched

Input: ?A&3/3/C)412&
Ignore: &/3C)
Find: A3C412&

was matched